# Extracting URL for each city in a list using Rvest

Tags: r, tidyverse, rvest

I have been exploring the rvest package and have a question regarding extracting urls from a list. My goal is to generate a df with the following headers: Country, City and the URL for the city. I already have a df with each of the countries and a list with the cities for each country.

My question is, how can I reference each city so that I can obtain its respective URL link? I am trying to reference the href inside the td class within "wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter" but when I run `links = webpage %>% html_node("href") %>% html_text()` I only get the main URL.

Thanks for the suggestions!

```
# Get URL
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_towns_and_cities_with_100,000_or_more_inhabitants/country:_A-B"

# Read the HTML code from the website
page = read_html(url)

# Get name of the countries
countries = page %>% html_nodes(".mw-headline") %>% html_text()

#Remove the last two items which are not countries
countries = as.tibble(countries) %>%
  slice(1:(n()-2))

#Add row number to each Country to left_join later
countries = rowid_to_column(countries, "column_label")

# Get cities for that country
# Still working on this since it includes the first table and I get blanks when I filter the html_nodes(".jquery-tablesorter td")
tables = html_nodes(page, "table")
tables = lapply(tables, html_table)

#Remove fist element which is not a city, only on the first page
tables = tables[-1]

#---WIP
# Get links for the cities, currently picks the main domain instead of the city
# Can I add a clause before the html node to indicate I want the href from "wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter"?
links = page %>% html_attr("href") %>% html_text()
#---

#Remove the Providence and Population columns and keeps City and URL
tables = lapply(tables, "[", -c(2, 3))

#Standardize City as the column
tables = map(tables, set_names, "City")

# Flatten List
all <- bind_rows(tables, .id = "column_label") %>%
  mutate(column_label = as.integer(column_label)) %>%
  left_join(countries, by = "column_label")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach to achieve your desired result may look like so. I took a different appraoch and use a small custom function to get your desired content by scraping the table rows:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

# Get a dataframe of city names and urls for one table
get_cities <- function(x) {
  x %>%
    html_nodes("tr") %>%
    .[-1] %>%
    # Get first column/cell containing city
    html_node("td a") %>%
    map_dfr(function(x) {
      data.frame(
        city = html_text(x),
        url = paste0("https://en.wikipedia.org",
                     html_attr(x, 'href'))
      )
    })
}

url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_towns_and_cities_with_100,000_or_more_inhabitants/country:_A-B"

# Read the HTML code from the website
webpage <- read_html(url)

# Get name of the countries
countries <- webpage %>%
  html_nodes(".mw-headline") %>%
  html_text()
countries <- countries[!grepl("(See also|References)", countries)]
# Get table nodes
tables <- webpage %>%
  html_nodes("table.wikitable.sortable")
names(tables) <- countries

res <- map_dfr(tables, get_cities, .id = "country")

head(res)
#>       country      city             url
#> 1 Afghanistan    Ghazni    /wiki/Ghazni
#> 2 Afghanistan     Herat     /wiki/Herat
#> 3 Afghanistan Jalalabad /wiki/Jalalabad
#> 4 Afghanistan     Kabul     /wiki/Kabul
#> 5 Afghanistan  Kandahar  /wiki/Kandahar
#> 6 Afghanistan     Khost     /wiki/Khost
```

Comment: Two questions, 
-Is there a way to include the URL format like the answer below? 
-I am assuming ".[-1] %>%" removes the first value of the List correct? What does the . before the [] mean for lists?

I will need to study the answer a bit because there are a lot of new concepts in it, thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi Raul. Correct. `.[-1]` removes the first element of the list. When using `%>%` the `.` is replaced by the value on the LHS of the pipe, whether a dataframe, a vector or a list (of nodes) as in the present case.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a fully reproducible example that gets you a table of the cities with their full url:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" %>%
  paste0('List_of_towns_and_cities_with_100,000_or_more_inhabitants/') %>%
  paste0('country:_A-B') %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "//table/tbody/tr") %>%
  lapply(function(x) {
    node <- xml2::xml_find_first(x, 'td/a') 
    data.frame(city = html_attr(node, 'title'), 
               url = paste0("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki",
                            html_attr(node, 'href')))}) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  remove_missing(na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  as_tibble()
#> # A tibble: 534 x 2
#>    city           url                                              
#>    <chr>          <chr>                                            
#>  1 Ghazni         https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/wiki/Ghazni        
#>  2 Herat          https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/wiki/Herat         
#>  3 Jalalabad      https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/wiki/Jalalabad     
#>  4 Kabul          https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/wiki/Kabul         
#>  5 Kandahar       https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/wiki/Kandahar      
#>  6 Khost          https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/wiki/Khost         
#>  7 Kunduz         https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/wiki/Kunduz        
#>  8 Lashkargah     https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/wiki/Lashkargah    
#>  9 Mazar-i-Sharif https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/wiki/Mazar-i-Sharif
#> 10 Mihtarlam      https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/wiki/Mihtarlam     
#> # ... with 524 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Is there a way to include the country on a column as well?